# Submitting form and success message on same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

So right now I have a basic contact.html with a php script set to email me if someone on my website contacts me. When they click submit, it takes them to contact_sent.php, which is a blank page. I want it so that when they click the submit, it keeps them on the same page, as well as display a success message from [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), and then clear the form so they can't spam the "Send Message" button.

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $message=$_POST['msg'];
    $to_add="***********@gmail.com";
    $from_add="form@***********.net";

    $email_message="<br /><br /><b>Name:</b><br />$name <br />";
    $email_message.="<br /><br /><b>Reply Email:</b><br />$email <br />";
    $email_message.="<br /><br /><b>Regarding:</b><br />$subject <br />";
    $email_message.="<br /><br /><b>Message:</b><br />$message <br />";

    $headers="From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers.="Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers.="Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers.="X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
    $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";

    mail($to_add,$subject,$email_message,$headers);
}
alert("Sent!");
?>
```

Edit: The alert at the end doesn't work.

Comment: alert is a js function not a php one

Comment: @Dagon Disregard that.

Comment: submit form to same page, separate form from response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is essentially what AJAX is. If you are using jquery you can use its $.ajax function on the button press and send the data via its data property. Based on your current PHP code it might look something like this:

```
 $.ajax({ url: '/route/to/php/function',
         data: {name = nameVal,
         email = emailVal,
         subject = subjectVal,
         message = messageVal},
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                      //do whatever after the POST is successful
                  }
});
```

You'd put the form clearing code and SweetAlert code in the same event listener for the submit button, either before or after the $.ajax call.

Comment: bah, this can be done with out ajax. not all answers are use ajax

Comment: I'd prefer to do this w/o AJAX, but if I have to, I'll use it.

Comment: As @Dagon said, it is not about using Ajax. It is about managing a result from a PHP point of view.
Ajax will only help you managing things without page refreshes.

Comment: Ajax = without page requiring to be refreshed.  You can also prevent form resubmissions easier this way.  I am not sure who down-voted this, but it is a viable solution based on the context of the question being asked.  The code `alert("foo");` is javascript.  The other solutions are decent as well, but take the user away from the original page. Ideally, use a combination of good php post handler, and ajax for ux.

Answer (score 3):

alert is javascript code.So you need your php script to produce that javascipt. Hope it will help you

```
<?php
    if($_POST['submit']) {
        //your other codes here

        mail($to_add,$subject,$email_message,$headers);
        //becareful keep the whole javascript code on mail function's success.
        //I just added how to do It.It will alert too if your mail function return false.
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Sent!");
        </script>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?
if ($_POST['submit'])
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$to_add = "***********@gmail.com";
$from_add = "form@***********.net";

$email_message = "<br /><br /><b>Name:</b><br />$name <br />";
$email_message .= "<br /><br /><b>Reply Email:</b><br />$email <br />";
$email_message .= "<br /><br /><b>Regarding:</b><br />$subject <br />";
$email_message .= "<br /><br /><b>Message:</b><br />$message <br />";

$headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;\r\n";

mail($to_add,$subject,$email_message,$headers);

//echo js alert
}else{ // form not submitted yet
//display form code

}

?>
```